# Non-Expanding TextBox / ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am attempting to place a TextBox control in a sizeable panel (using the GridSplitter).

The first issue I experienced was that the TextBox was automatically sizing as the text being entred became lengthy.  I found a solution on this site that wraps the TextBox with a Border and then sets the Width of the TextBox to that of the Border (as displayed in the XAML below).  This appears to be working.  I mention this in case it is the cause of the issue that I am seeking help on.

The current issue is that the TextBox resizes up but the ScrollViewer kicks in immediately when the panel is resized down.  What I would like to see is the ScrollViewer kick in when the TextBox is sized down to the minimum width (and not before).

The complete XAML that I am currently using is below.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Class="NonExpandingTextBoxDemo.MainWindow" Height="350" Title="MainWindow" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20, 20, 20, 20" MinWidth="100" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Width="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" />
      </Border>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="3" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Right Panel" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The question is what am I missing?  I have tried several things but nothing seems to work.

Thank you in advance for any guidance on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the ScrollViewer. See, the ScrollViewer is not configured to resize its children when it gets smaller, only bigger. Hence you see the child elements grow but not shrink.

Why do you need a ScrollViewer?

```
<Window x:Class="TextWrappingAtParentSize.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="FirstCol" MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20, 20, 20, 20" >
                <TextBox Width="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Border>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="3" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Right Panel" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

By putting the MinWidth on the column, there may never be a need to scroll. However, I realize this may just be a sample and you may have other needs to scroll.

I can keep looking for a scrolling solution. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  My thought process is something like what if I want the minimum width of the TextBox elements (or whatever content is in the ScrollViewer) to have, say, a minimum width of 200 but the user sizes the panel down to a width of 100.  In this case, I want to be able to show the entire area (albeit through scrolling).  I guess I could set the minimum width of the panel to the minimum width of the content.  However, the form where this will eventually appear has quite a bit going on so I want to make the most out of the space.

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was similar.  I had a scrollviewer wrapping a grid where I needed the TexBlock to expand with the column and wrap the text.  I was able to achieve this by creating a Converter.

```
public class ValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int width;

        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out width) && width > 0)
        {
            return width - int.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The name of the containing ScrollViewer is "scrollViewerDetails", so I passed its width to the converter.  The ConverterParamter (170) is the width of the first column that I need to subtract from the overall width.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Width="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewerDetails, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource ValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=170}" />
```